# How to end the execution of an Event in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am using an Event which is triggered by timeout and cyclic in AnyLogic. After a certain condition is true I want to stop the event from executing asap. It needs to be via code.Something similar to .stop(),.finish() or.cancel().

I tried various instructions that I am familiar with to stop executing codes and so on. None of them worked (which I expected to be honest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reset()` function does that for you:
[image]

And if you want to resume the cyclic event after stopping it above, call `event.resume()`:)